# MYSQL- command for copy value in column with same id

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, sqlcommand

i need help to create the right MySQL command.
As you can see in attachment ,
i need to copy string from column value with **attribute_id 78** in column value with **attribute_id 77** WHERE the **entity_id** is the same.

can anyone help me write the right code?
Thanks in advance

[screenshot sql tabble](https://i.stack.imgur.com/alRJA.jpg)

Comment: I might be wrong, but I didn't think phpmyadmin supported SQL Server. Are you *really* using SQL Server?

Comment: i'm sorry MySQL!

Answer (score 0):

This will do it:

```
UPDATE T
SET value = A.value
FROM
    YourTable T
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT TOP 1 value
        FROM YourTable
        WHERE
            [entity_id] = T.[entity_id]
            AND attribute_id = 78
    ) A
WHERE attribute_id = 77
```

Comment: I have executed your query but I receive this error

Comment: UPDATE T
SET value = A.value
FROM
    'mage_catalog_product_entity_varchar' T
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT TOP 1 value
        FROM 'mage_catalog_product_entity_varchar'
        WHERE

            [entity_id] = T.[entity_id]
            AND attribute_id = 78
    ) A
WHERE attribute_id = 77
Messaggio di MySQL: Documentazione

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM
    'mage_catalog_product_entity_varchar' T
    CROSS APPLY
    (
     ' at line 3

Comment: Ah, you're using MySQL, not SQL Server.

Comment: I'm sorry I messed up!

Comment: No problem, easy mistake - you're here to learn after all. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is based on that the OP is really using SQL Server (which I highly doubt, as they have tagged `phpmyadmin`).

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT [value],
           LEAD([value]) OVER (PARTITION BY entity_id ORDER BY attribute_id) AS NextValue
    FROM YourTable
    WHERE attribute_id IN (77,78))
UPDATE CTE
SET value = NextValue
WHERE attribute_id = 77;
```

Comment: i'm sorry i mean Mysql!

Comment: [link](https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/3045812/a80de85fa5716f57d8c20e74ed35124c)